# Changing x and y values of a Sprite Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm attempting to change the x and y value of a sprite.

```
    public var panContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var xVal:Number;
    public var yVal:Number;
```

I've created the function:

```
    public function moveContainer(xVal,yVal):void
    {
        xVal = panContainer.x;
        yVal = panContainer.y;
    }
```

Both the variable and function are created within an .as file. I'm attempting to make the function call within a class file called test2.as using a case statement. When the user selects an item from a list box the sprite's x and y values need to change:

```
    switch (event.target.selectedItem.data)
                {
                  case 1 :
                  panZoomMap.moveContainer(30,30);
                  break;
```

The function call, however does nothing at this point. Is this a scope issue? Am I not executing this properly? Thanks in advance for any advise.

Comment: It's difficult to tell if this is a scope issue because this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You shouldn't start AS3 programming by untyping your parameters. Also some essential concepts are to be well understood. moveContainer(xVal,yVal) should be moveContainer(xVal:Number ,yVal:Number) but probably more important is the fact that those parameters have the exact same name than your variables (xVal and xVal for example). AS3 does allow you to do that because those name conflicts are following the scope rule. If no access is specified then the local scope is used meaning xVal is the parameter while this.xVal is your variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have your variable assignments backwards, what you want to do is assign the values you get in `moveContainer` to the `x` and `y` properties of `panContainer`:

```
public function moveContainer(xVal,yVal):void
{
    panContainer.x = xVal;
    panContainer.y = yVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am reading your question wrong (it is not worded well), you have this backwards

```
public function moveContainer(xVal,yVal):void
{
    panContainer.x = xVal;
    panContainer.y = yVal;
}
```

You were setting your variables to the x,y coords of your object, when you should have been setting your x,y coords to your variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Being new to Actionscript 3 I find it difficult to ask questions in a way that is easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close, just have it reversed.  You are passing in the xVal and yVal into the moveContainer method.  so xVal and yVal are the new values.  Below should be your function:

```
public function moveContainer(xVal,yVal):void
{
    panContainer.x = xVal;
    panContainer.y = yVal;
}
```

A simple rule of thumb I go by is: values always get assigned into a container to the left of the = sign.

So in the method will assign passed xVal to the `panContainer.x` property, and yVal to `panContainer.y` property.